# ¿Como puedo mostrar un div por url?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un sistema de usuarios y en el panel de usuario quiero que me muestre divs dependiendo a la url, Ejemplo: `pagina.com/usuario.php#div1` me muestre el div1 con sus datos, y si ingresa `pagina.com/usuario.php#div2` oculte el div1 y muestre el div2, de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido, te invito a que hagas el [tour] para conocer más acerca del sitio y de paso ganes tu ¡Primer medalla!, Así mismo lee [ask] y [mcve] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con PHP no es posible hacerlo ya que este no recibe el hash de la url en ninguna de sus variables, con javascript puedes tener algo como:

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
    Soy el div 1
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
    Soy el div 2
</div>

<script>
    var divId = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    document.getElementById(divId).style.display = '';
</script>
```

Con su respectivo control de errores ya que no siempre tendrá un hash que evaluar. Pero ya que estás con PHP creo que hay formas más simples de hacer que te muestre una porción de tu formulario según variables enviadas desde frontend, por ejemplo, haciendo uso de variables GET en vez de usar el HASH `pagina.com/usuario.php?mostrar=div1`

Answer (score 0):

usar una url con # no es la mejor forma de hacerlo, deberías hacerlo con un parametro get quedando así:

pagina.com/usuario.php?div=1 y pagina.com/usuario.php?div=2

entonces puedes obtener el valor del parámetro get usando javascript, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
  let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1));
  let numeroDiv = params.get('div'); //en la variable numeroDiv quedará el valor asignado en la URL
  mostrarDiv(numeroDiv);
}



//Esta función recibe el numero del div que se va a mostrar
var mostrarDiv = function(numeroDiv) {
  if(numeroDiv==1) {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva